# Dropping the 3rd variable in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following text:
loadeddata={{1,2,3},{5,2,1},{1,4,1},{1,5,0},{2,3,5}}

How can I removed the third numbers in each of the sublists?

The real data has 600 of these sublists. I want to use Histogram3D with the first two variables.

Comment: `loadeddata[[All, {1, 2}]]` or `loadeddata[[All, 1 ;; 2]]`

Comment: I think people are too quick to vote close on newbies.

Comment: If you like to use a pattern then loadeddata /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, b}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a convenience function for you:

```
DropColumn[mat_, n_] := Module[
    {toDrop, toKeep, numberOfColumns, normalized, fixNegs},
    numberOfColumns = Length[mat[[1]]];
    fixNegs = Function[If[Less[#, 0], numberOfColumns + # + 1, #]];
    toDrop = If[ListQ[n], Map[fixNegs, n], {fixNegs @ n}];
    toKeep = Complement[Range @ numberOfColumns, toDrop];
    Return[mat[[All, toKeep]]]
   ];
```

Here's how you use it:

```
loadeddata = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 5, 0}, {2, 3, 5}};
loadeddata = DropColumn[loadeddata, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what advantage it has over `loadeddata[[All, 1 ;; 2]]`?

Comment: Let's you specify the columns you want to delete as opposed to the columns you don't?

Comment: I see, makes sense. If you disagree with closing you can vote to reopen.